# JAX-RS and Spring Security - obtaining authenticated user

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, jersey, jax-rs

I am currently implementing REST API using *Jersey* (JAX-RS impelemntation) and some parts of *Spring*.

I already implemented stateless authentication with *Spring Security* using custom filter and custom `AuthenticationEntryPoint`, the problem is, how can I obtain current user in my *JAX-RS* classes.

I know that in *Spring MVC* it is possible to inject `Principal` object into controller methods, but what about *JAX-RS* classes? I want to avoid polluting my classes with `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()`.

One way is to create custom class that will be an adapter to this static call, and inject it into every service class I need, or maybe there is this kind of adapter already exposed in *Spring Security*?  Apart from my proposal, is there some 'better' way of obtaining currently logged user in my situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With JAX-RS, you'd probably want to define a way of [creating custom entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047400/using-context-provider-and-contextresolver-in-jax-rs) that could be injected with `@Context`. Unfortunately, the JAX-RS specification doesn't state how to do this, but implementations of it do. For example, CXF (which works well with Spring) would do it like this:

```
public class AuthenticationContextProvider implements ContextProvider<Authentication> {
    public Authentication createContext(Message message) {
        return SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    }
}
```

You'd then have to register that provider, which would then let you do:

```
@GET
@Path("/{id}")
@Produces("text/plain")
public String demonstration(@PathParam("id") String id,
        @Context UriInfo ui, @Context Authentication auth) {
    // ...
```

You can do something similar with Jersey (as the above linked question indicates) but I don't know Jersey nearly so well.

Comment: I'm almost tempted to go off and implement this in my own code now that I've looked up how to do it. Except it's my Christmas break…

Answer (score -1):

You can inject the HttpServletRequest using the @Context annotation. This works both for JAX-RS Resource Methods parameters and JAX-RS Resource Fields. Maybe this can help you ?