# Authentication/authorization in JAX-RS using interceptors and injection

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee, jax-rs, restful-authentication, wildfly

I am developing a new application in JavaEE 7 using WildFly 8. I am using JAX-RS to provide a RESTful service interface for remote applications.

Something like an `HttpHeaders` object can be injected in a resource method arguments using the `@Context` annotation. Since the object is based on request parameters (of course, the HTTP headers), I came up with the idea of creating my own injectable `User` object which is created based on the presence of a valid token in the request (something like an OAuth access token).

So, I want to achieve something like this:

```
@Path("/resources")
public class MyResource {

    @Path("/{id}")
    @GET
    public Response getById(@Context User user, @PathParam("id") long id) {
        ...
    }

}
```

Where User is an injectable object created based on request parameters, such as ones accessible through an `HttpHeaders` object. Of course, the provider can also throw an exception and return an HTTP error response if the User object cannot be created for any reason.

Now, my questions are:

1. Is this a good design? If not, what better options do I have?
2. How can I achieve this? I do not care if my solution is not JAX-RS specific and uses WildFly/RestEasy-specific internals, but I definitely prefer a portable solution if there exists one.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my eyes this approach is valid as long as you don't try to build something like a session with this User Object.

As [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047400/using-context-provider-and-contextresolver-in-jax-rs) you could use [@Context](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Context.html) and [@Provider](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/Provider.html) but that's not exactly what you want.
Directly injecting a Class per `@Context` is possible with the [Resteasy Dispatcher](http://bill.burkecentral.com/2011/03/09/adding-objects-that-are-context-injectable/).
But here you must register the Object which should be injected. I don't think that makes sense for request-scoped parameters.
What you could do is inject a provider like this:

```
// Constructor of your JAX-RS Application
public RestApplication(@Context Dispatcher dispatcher) {
    dispatcher.getDefaultContextObjects().put(UserProvider.class, new UserProvider());
}

// a resource
public Response getById(@Context UserProvider userProvider) {
    User user = userProvider.get();
}
```

Other ways to solve your problem:

1. Register a [WebFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebFilter.html), authenticate the user, wrap the ServletRequest and override [getUserPrincipal](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getUserPrincipal()). You can then access the UserPrincipal from a injected HttpServletRequest.
2. Implement a JAX-RS Interceptor which implements [ContainerRequestFilter](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestFilter.html). Use [ContainerRequestContext.html#setSecurityContext](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestContext.html#setSecurityContext(javax.ws.rs.core.SecurityContext)) with a UserPrincipal and inject the SecurityContext as ResourceMethod-Parameter.
3. Implement a [CDI-Interceptor](https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.0.0/en-US/html/interceptors.html) which updates your Method-Parameters.
4. Implement a class [which produces](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/inject/Produces.html) your user and inject it via CDI.

I pushed  examples to [github](https://github.com/lefloh/jax-rs-context).

Answer (score 5):

While lefloh's answer is definitely correct I'd like to elaborate on his 2nd approach which I find most convenient.

You're to create Interceptor(Filter) which implements [ContainerRequestFilter](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.9.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html#Interceptors).

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory;

import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
import java.io.IOException;

@Provider
public class UserProvider implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext) throws IOException {
        String userId = containerRequestContext.getHeaders().getFirst("User-Id");
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(userId)) {
            Response response = Response
                    .status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST)
                    .type(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE)
                    .entity("User-Id header is missing.")
                    .build();
            containerRequestContext.abortWith(response);
            return;
        }

        //do your logic to obtain the User object by userId

        ResteasyProviderFactory.pushContext(User.class, user);
    }
}
```

You'd need to register it either by autodiscovering [set up in web.xml](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.9.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html#d4e125)

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

or in your app boot

```
ResteasyProviderFactory.getInstance().registerProvider(UserProvider.class);
```

Since all the logic behind fetching the user is in the UserProvider you can for example use it like this

```
@Path("/orders")
@GET
public List<Order> getOrders(@Context User user) {
    return user.getOrders();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you have any ideas how this can be made portable across JEE containers?

Comment: resteasy.scan is totally deprecated. It just gets ignored.