# jaxrs/resteasy custom method paramater

Tags: rest, jax-rs, resteasy

I would like to have my JaxRs resource to take a custom method argument that is built from some parameter in the request.
Something to be used in conjunction with another object created from the body.
Something like:

```
 @Resource
 public class MyResource {
      @Path("/resource")
      public Object resource(MyResourceDTO body, AConfiguration conf){

      }
 }
```

For which the `AConfiguration` is created from some headers in the request.

How can I achive it?

I need something like th spring webargumentresovler: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/support/WebArgumentResolver.html

For my case `MyResource` is a subresource, the method should work also in this case...

Comment: There is no issue with body carrying an object. Do you want pass a configuration object through your header?

Comment: I would like to create `AConfiguration` from the HttpRequest, like taking 2 Headers and 1 query parameter, or stuff like this, customizing the creation of the object

Comment: [My answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29028880/3249097) over here pretty much solves your use case. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

If you add a DTO as parameter of your resource method your JAX-RS runtime will try to convert the body of the request into this type. You can additionally add any of the `@xParam` parameters like `@QueryParam` as parameters of your resource method. (The only exception is `@FormParam` as they are found in the body).

If you want to encapsulate multiple of your Params in one object you can use [@BeanParam](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/BeanParam.html). Your Configuration class could look like this:

```
public class Configuration {

    @QueryParam("foo")
    private String foo;

    @HeaderParam("bar")
    private String bar;

    // getters + setters

}
```

And can be used like this:

```
@POST
public Response someMethod(Dto dto, @BeanParam Configuration conf) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like below. Your `conf` object have be sent as `json` from the client. If the parameters in `conf` object have to change dynamically you have to follow the second approach.

```
 @Resource
 public class MyResource {

      @POST
      @Consumes("application/json")
      @Path("/resource")
      public Object resource(AConfiguration conf){
      // This method can receive multiple objects here. Currently it receives
      // conf object only as the payload of the post method.  
      }

 }
```

To change the conf object dynamically, You can send `json` String.

```
      public Object resource(String confJson){
      // Collect parameters manually here.
      }
```

In your `pom.xml`, you should include,

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.GA</version>
  </dependency>
```

**Edit:**

You can set a json string as a header param (But, not the best practice.) Or you can set different headers at you will and access them using HttpHeaders. [Here](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/get-http-header-in-jax-rs/) is an example.

```
      public Object resource(@Context HttpHeaders confHeaders){
      // Collect parameters manually.
      String confJson = confHeaders.getRequestHeader("confJson").get(0);
      // cast your `confJson` to `AConfiguration aConf` here.
      // process query params and set them to aConf here.
      }
```

Comment: I already have a Json sent, the conf should be build from headers

Comment: @rascio I added another example. Check it out.

Comment: But with `@Context` annotation can I use a custom object? To create `AConfiguration` I need to do some calculation on some headers and querystring parameters. I would like to pass the calculated object to the resource instead of the raw headers and parameters.

Comment: @rascio If you want to get the calculated object to the resource, I think you will have to implement a `PreProcessInterceptor` (http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/1.1.GA/userguide/html/Interceptors.html). Else I will modify my example, so you can process it in the resource.