# jboss Resteasy parameter injection with @Context

Tags: java, rest, jboss, jax-rs, resteasy

I'm doing a token based authentication using jboss 7.1  and resteasy.
I'm using a PreProcessInterceptor to intercept request, get token, retrieve user from token and then check user roles against custom annotations placed on the method. What I want to do now is to inject User into the method like folowing.

```
@Path("/doStuffWithUser")
@GET
@Requires("ADMIN") // custom annotation
public Response doStuffWithUser(@Context User user);
```

I know this is very close from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23035316/authentication-authorization-in-jax-rs-using-interceptors-and-injection) question and I have tried addapting the differents solutions proposed on the [linked github example](https://github.com/lefloh/jax-rs-context) but I can't find a way to inject the user from within my PreProcessInterceptor.

Thanks

Comment: is there a jax-rs agnostic way ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is the solution I finnaly found:

```
PreProcessInterceptor.preProcess(..){
    ... 
    retrieve User from token
    check roles
    ...
    //add the user to the context data
    ResteasyProviderFactory.pushContext(User.class, user);

}
```

You can then retrieve the User with the notation I used in my question.

Hope it will help someone.

Comment: is there a jax-rs agnostic way?

Comment: PreProcessInterceptor is deprecated in Resteasy 3.x. In 3.x version, this can be done using javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter . See http://stackoverflow.com/a/17597783/122975 for more informations