# @Context object not injected when unit testing resteasy

Tags: java, unit-testing, jboss, jax-rs, resteasy

I'm trying to register a @Provider which would inject Locale object into the @Context so that I can reuse it in my REST resources.

Following the article http://bill.burkecentral.com/2011/03/09/adding-objects-that-are-context-injectable/ I managed to get the provider running

```
@Provider
public class LocaleProvider implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    public static final String DEFAULT_LANGUAGE_CODE_VALUE = "en-US";

    @Context
    Dispatcher dispatcher;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext) throws IOException {
        List<Locale> acceptableLanguages = containerRequestContext.getAcceptableLanguages();
        if (acceptableLanguages == null || acceptableLanguages.isEmpty()) {
(A)         dispatcher.getDefaultContextObjects().put(Locale.class, new Locale(DEFAULT_LANGUAGE_CODE_VALUE));
            return;
        }

        dispatcher.getDefaultContextObjects().put(Locale.class, acceptableLanguages.get(0));
    }


}
```

And use it like this

```
@Path("/")
public class Resource {

    @GET
    public String get(@Context Locale locale) {
        if (locale == null) {
            return "null";
        }

        return locale.getLanguage();
    }
}
```

The code so far works great when deployed to Tomcat. But I run into **an issue when I try to unit test it**. I have

```
public class LocaleProviderTest {
    private Dispatcher dispatcher = MockDispatcherFactory.createDispatcher();

    {
        dispatcher.getRegistry().addResourceFactory(new POJOResourceFactory(Resource.class));
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldHaveDefaultLocaleWhenNoAcceptLanguageHeader() throws URISyntaxException {
        dispatcher.getProviderFactory().registerProvider(LocaleProvider.class);

        MockHttpRequest request = MockHttpRequest.get("/");
        MockHttpResponse response = new MockHttpResponse();
        dispatcher.invoke(request, response);

        assertEquals("en", response.getContentAsString());
    }
}
```

The Resource returns `null` even though the LocaleProvider executes the line `(A)` if I debug it.

Any idea **why the @Context injection does not work when unit testing?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26279362/3249097).

In my LocaleProvider instead of

```
 dispatcher.getDefaultContextObjects().put(Locale.class, locale);
```

I needed to use

```
 ResteasyProviderFactory.pushContext(Locale.class, locale);
```

Hope it helps someone :)

Comment: Thanks, it works!!! But in the newer versions of Resteasy, the  ResteasyProviderFactory.pushContext method no longer exists. I had to use ResteasyContext.pushContext instead