# Context injected SecurityContext is null

Tags: java, dependency-injection, jax-rs, resteasy, security-context

I have created a Javae EE app using JAX-RS 2.0 and JPA. I created a special provider of my User entity (using Qualifiers) to provide the current user (logged in) as entity from applications user database.
To get current user i use

```
@Context
private SecurityContext secContext;
```

The problem is that this is null. The security is setup fine (Wildfly 8.2) - the app asks for Authentication (basic) but `SecurityContext` is null. Here is the code:

```
@RequestScoped
public class CurrentUserProducer implements Serializable {

    /**
     * Default
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Context
    private SecurityContext secContext;

    /**
     * Tries to find logged in user in user db (by name) and returns it. If not
     * found a new user with role {@link UserRole#USER} is created.
     * 
     * @return found user a new user with role user
     */
    @Produces
    @CurrentUser
    public User getCurrentUser() {
        if (secContext == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Can't inject security context - security context is null.");
        //... code to retrieve or create new user
        return user;
    }

}
```

As you see I check `secContext` for null and i see my exception as soon as i try to reach a resource that injects `@CurrentUser`.

So how to fix this? Why is `SecurityContext` null.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in my comment

> `SecurityContext` is a JAX-RS component and can only be injected into other JAX-RS component. All you have is a CDI bean. You can try to make it an EJB and inject `SessionContext`. See Securing an [Enterprise Bean Programmatically](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbyl.html#gjgcs)

Haven't tested but seems to work for the OP. This is a EE stack solution.

Another JAX-RS (Resteasy specific) way to allow for injection is with the help of the [`ResteasyProviderFactory`](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0-rc-1/javadocs/org/jboss/resteasy/spi/ResteasyProviderFactory.html) (found with help from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26279362/2587435)). You could use this in a `ContainerRequestFilter`, which has access to the `SecurityContext`. We can use the RESTeasy utility class to push the `User` into the context. This allows for injection with the `@Context` annotation. Not sure how/if it would work with a custom annotation though.  Here's an example

```
@Provider
public class UserContextFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext context) throws IOException {
        SecurityContext securityContext = context.getSecurityContext();
        String username = securityContext.getUserPrincipal().getName();

        ResteasyProviderFactory.pushContext(User.class, new User(username));
    }  
}
```

Note: this is a JAX-RS 2.0 solution (i.e. RESTeasy 3.x.x). Prior to 2.0, there is no `ContainerRequestFilter`

Comment: i am trying to strictly rely on Java EE standards. But as i said with implementing "ContextResolver" it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I found another way to get the class recognized by Jax-Rs: Implementing ContextResolver and annotating the class with provider.

To implement the interface i added:

```
@Override
public User getContext(Class<?> type) {
    if (type.equals(User.class)){
        return getCurrentUser();
    }
    return null;
}
```

I am not sure but probably with this i can do

@Context
private User currentUser;

But i didn't try. But the injection via qualifier is working now (security context is injected).

Comment: Interesting solution. I've never thought of doing this. Have you tried this injection of `User` to see it it works?

Comment: no i didn't tried yet - i would have to refactor seome code (including tests). But at least all Context stuff will be injected in a class annotated with @Provider (need to implement some jax-rs interface)