# Using Guice to inject values that are generated at runtime

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I have a Context class that is a key value pair that is populated gradually at runtime.

I would like to create instances of objects that require some values from the context.

For example:

```
public interface Task
{
    void execute();
}

public interface UiService
{
    void moveToHomePage();
}

public class UiServiceImpl implements UiService
{
    public UiService(@ContexParam("username") String username, @ContexParam("username") String password)
    {
        login(username, password);
    }

    public void navigateToHomePage() {}

    private void login(String username, String password) 
    {
        //do login
    }
}

public class GetUserDetailsTask implements Task
{
    private ContextService context;

    @Inject
    public GetUserDetailsTask(ContextService context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void execute()
    {
        Console c = System.console();
        String username = c.readLine("Please enter your username: ");
        String password = c.readLine("Please enter your password: ");
        context.add("username", username);
        context.add("password", password);
    }
}

public class UseUiServiceTask implements Task
{
    private UiService ui;

    @Inject
    public UseUiServiceTask(UiService uiService)

    public void execute()
    {
        ui.moveToHomePage();
    }
}
```

I want to be able to create an instance of UseUiServiceTask using Guice. 
How do I achieve that?

Comment: Have you tried with a Provider ?

Comment: If I get it right provider does not work in my case. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I was thinking of things like in http://stackoverflow.com/a/15493413/4462333
If it doesn't workout, I might have misunderstood something in your question. Could you edit it to add more code/information related to your problem ?

Comment: My Context is not related to web development. Think about it as a hash table that will grow when my application is running. I will update my question to clarify.

Comment: What should happen when Foo is created but Bar does not exist at that point?

Comment: @mlk - imagine that I run my program for some time. Some component will add "bar" to the context. Only after that I will run: injector.getInstance<Foo>()

Comment: In that case a Provider where you only call "Provider.get" in " `doSomethingWithBar`" would make the most sense to me. Else you will have to do some funky wrapping.

Comment: @mlk - but a provider will do if I had only 1 class like Foo. Imagine I have many with this requirement.

Comment: Provide us with your real use-case: your question is way too broad (lots of "if", "imagine", etc.) and unclear at this moment (`Context` is both a concrete class and an annotation in yout question).

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire - I added a concrete example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data are just that: data. Don't inject data unless it's defined before you get your modules and it's constant for the rest of the application.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Console c = System.console();
  String username = c.readLine("Please enter your username: ");
  String password = c.readLine("Please enter your password: ");

  Guice.createInjector(new LoginModule(username, password));
}
```

If you want your data to be retrieved after the injection has started, you should not try to inject it at all. What you should do then is injecting your `ContextService` everywhere you need it, and/or call callbacks, but I prefer callbacks for not having to maintain the data centrally.

```
public class LoginRequestor {
  String username, password;
  public void requestCredentials() {
    Console c = System.console();
    username = c.readLine("Please enter your username: ");
    password = c.readLine("Please enter your password: ");
  }
}

public class UiServiceImpl implements UiService {
  @Inject LoginRequestor login;
  boolean loggedIn;

  public void navigateToHomePage() {
    checkLoggedIn();
  }
  private void checkLoggedIn() {
    if (loggedIn) {
      return;
    }
    login.requestCredentials();
    String username = login.getUsername();
    String password = login.getPassword();
    // Do login
    loggedIn = ...;
  }
}
```