# How do I make a custom context object that can be injected with @Context?

Tags: jax-rs, quarkus

I want to be able to do something like this:

```java
@GET
@Path("test")
public Response someMethod(@Context MyCustomContext myCustomContext) {
 ...
}
```

I found this old stack overflow post that describes different methods for doing this here: [Using @Context, @Provider and ContextResolver in JAX-RS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047400/using-context-provider-and-contextresolver-in-jax-rs).  I implemented the top answer (which is implementation agnostic) and got it to work, but it didn't do exactly what I want.  Instead it looked this:

```java
@GET
@Path("test")
public Response someMethod(@Context Providers providers) {
        ContextResolver<MyCustomContext> p = providers.getContextResolver(MyCustomContext.class, MediaType.WILDCARD_TYPE);
        MyCustomContext myCustomContext = p.getContext(null);
       ... 
}
```

There were some other solutions on that post, but they were implementation dependent. I noticed in the quarkus docs that there was a section on custom contexts that can be found here: https://quarkus.io/guides/cdi-reference#synthetic-beans, but this is specific for extensions.  Does anyone have ideas on how to do this in a quarkus project?

Comment: Any solution is going to be (JAX-RS) implementation specific.

Comment: You're right.  I think I came up with a solution I like though. I ended up using `ResteasyContext`.  So what I did was put `ResteasyContext.pushContext(User.class, currentUser);` into a jaxrs filter, which allowed me to do `@Context User currentUser`.